# Swift -How to make a passthrough view recognize a down swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a second window that has a view with a `passthrough view` inside of it. The passthrough works fine but I need it to recognize `downSwipe gestures` while still passing all other touch events to the view below it. How can I do this?

```
class PassThroughView: UIView {
    
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        print("Passing all touches to the next view (if any), in the view stack.")
        return false
    }
}

class MyVC: UIViewController {

    lazy var backdropView: PassThroughView = {
        let v = PassThroughView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        v.backgroundColor = .clear 
        v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear

        addGesture()    
    }

    func addGesture() {

        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
        backdropView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    }

    @objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
   
       if gesture.direction == .down {
            print("Swipe Down")
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example code, you haven't added the `backdropView ` to the ctrl's view..

Comment: I didn’t add it because it’s just a subView of the vc: `view.addSubview(backdropView)` it’s pinned to all sides. Adding it makes no difference to the question.

Comment: well in the example i didnt see this line `view.addSubview(backdropView)`

Comment: did you managed to fix this issue? because the `point` method doesn't differs between a single touch or a swipe

Comment: I’m using a SwipeGesture with `.direction = .down`. How does it not distinguish between a touch or a swipe with this code? Your losing me

Comment: I've just implemented the `PassThroughView ` code and added swipe gesture to the view. 
In all cases (eg tap, swipe) the event.type is always `.touch`.. so I can't figure out how to differ if the event in the `point` func was a swipe event, that I would like to trigger and not stop, and or a tap the I would like to pass trough to the bottom view..

Comment: I have no idea. I never figured this out and just moved on. I used a different setup. If you can figure it out and it works I’ll accept it. Maybe it’ll help someone else.